# Linux how to move space from one partition to another

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, fedora

I am not familiar with Linux OS configuration. I need you help to **move more space from one partition to another**. I have this **disk usage** right now:

$ df -h

```
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/fedora-root   41G  4.9G   34G  13% /
devtmpfs                 3.6G     0  3.6G   0% /dev
tmpfs                    3.6G  592K  3.6G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    3.6G  672K  3.6G   1% /run
tmpfs                    3.6G     0  3.6G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                    3.6G   28K  3.6G   1% /tmp
/dev/sda1                477M   90M  358M  20% /boot
/dev/mapper/fedora-home   20G   19G   17M 100% /home
```

The **fedora-home** partition is where I am working at. It is full now. The **fedora-root** partition has many unused spaces and nobody will use them. I want to move 20GB from **fedora-root** to **fedora-home**. How can I do it?

I searched online and didn't find **direct** instruction for this. Hope I can get **direct** instruction here because I don't want to just try something with the risk of losing my data. This is my personal computer and I am running Fedora 20.

There is only one physic disk.

The **$fdisk -l** result is this:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 68.2 GiB, 73275408384 bytes, 143116032 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000b8590

Device    Boot     Start       End   Blocks  Id System
/dev/sda1 *         2048   1026047   512000  83 Linux
/dev/sda2        1026048 143114239 71044096  8e Linux LVM


Disk /dev/mapper/fedora-swap: 6.8 GiB, 7327449088 bytes, 14311424 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/fedora-root: 41 GiB, 43956305920 bytes, 85852160 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/fedora-home: 20 GiB, 21462253568 bytes, 41918464 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK to shrink a root partition you have to boot from a Live CD. Take any linux live cd with GParted in it, shrink the root partition, resize the home partition.
Enlarging a partition without moving it is safe for data, but while shrinking the root partition don't interrupt the process (it may be slow, be patient and just wait; or backup the data beforehand).